# Switching off the mousepad but not the mouse

Tags: 18.04, mouse

A tiny drop of blood, sweat, and teas (sic) on my HP ProBook makes the pointing device go mad for some time, despite all my drying efforts.

Is there any simple way to use the external (water resistant up to 200m) mouse only, entirely bypassing the touchpad?

Comment: In Systems Settings, Touchpad & Mouse, you should be able to turn the Touchpad off.

Comment: Settings -> **Devices** -> Touchpad & Mouse is it, thx!